Why is the JwtStrategy not called by NestJS AuthGuard?
I tried to implement the Jwt-Authentication Guard on a backend built with NestJS.
Although my JwtAuthGuard will be initiated, and although Bearer tokens will created accordingly in my auth-service during the login-endpoint, the final Guard at the end is never being executed.
This is my jwt-auth.guard.ts:
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    console.log('canActivate', JwtAuthGuard.name);
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    console.log('Is Public', isPublic);
    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}

The part around "isPublic" is identifying whether an Endpoint should be publicly available or not.
This is the jwt.strategy:
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {
    console.log(
      'Initializing JwtStrategy',
      configService.get<string>('jwt.secret'),
    );
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('jwt.secret'),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    console.log('validating JwtStrategy');
    const user = await this.usersService.findOneByUUID(payload.sub);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}

The constructor will be executed as I can see the corresponding line in the console-log.
In the Controller for User-related endpoints, I have the following method:
  @Roles(Role.User)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('/profile')
  async profile(@CurrentUser() currentUser, @CurrentClient() currentClient) {
    return this.userService.profile(currentUser, currentClient);
  }

It will always fail due to "user not authorized" independently wether the user has been authorized and fetched a Bearer token or not.
I figured out, that the validate-function in the Jwt-Strategy class will never be executed.
I don't know what happens inside the passport-library but it has nothing to do with my expectations according to the official docs and any tutorial.
What do I miss?
